# Why does cin cause this program to hang?

Tags: c++, cin

I have posted the relevant code below. When I compile the program, it runs and reaches the point where it waits for the input. I type in an integer and press ENTER, but the code never continues. How would I go about correcting this?

```
int i;
cout << "Please input column to sort by: ";
cin >> i;
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code (provided you are not accidentally using a different `cin` and `cout` than the ones in `std`. What is the code directly before and after this snippet?

Comment: Is that the whole program? If not, did you try the code alone with the same compiler? If it works, then it's something else making your cin hang.

Comment: Show the code that follows this.  Preferably a full compilable example that performs the undesired behavior.

Comment: if that's all the code you wrote there should be no problem, can you plz provide some more code? i mean what you do after cin?

Comment: What compiler/IDE/OS are you using? And how do you recognize that the "code never continues"?

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, what you posted above won't compile. Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    std::cout << "Please input column to sort by: ";
    std::cin >> i;
    std::cout << "You entered: " << i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `g++ -O3 thefile.cpp`, assuming the file is called "thefile.cpp".

If it doesn't work then there is a serious issue going on. If it does you should be able to diagnose your issue further.

Comment: It ended up being a compiler issue. I reinstalled it and it magically works.

Answer (score 1):

If you use visual studio 2010 try this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int i;
  cout<<"Please input column to sort by: ";
  cin>>i;
  cout<<"Your input the number: "<<i<<"\n\n";

  system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```